# Strange Code: JS Console.log() outputs twice with different output

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, console, razor

I am trying to read an ID from a table row in my html via a checkbox/edit button contained in the row. The row has id of "name_id#" Here is the code:

```
$('.EditButton').click(function edit() {
        var patchID = parseInt($(this).attr('id').slice(5));
        console.log("patchID is : " + patchID.toString());
...
});
```

I have tried using substring and slice, and without parseInt. Everything seems to grab the ID number correctly, however when I log it, it outputs this:

> patchID is : 63 
>   patchID is : NaN

Is there something totally wrong with my code? When I try and use a jquery "get" using the ID, it works, but it also throws an error because it tries to "get" with both the ID # and "NaN".

Here is the html for my table rows:

```
@foreach (var patch in patches)
                {
                    <tr id=@string.Format("patch_{0}", patch.PatchID)>
                      <td>
                            <div class="EditButton">
                                <input type="button" class="button EditButton" 
                                       value="" 
                                       id=@string.Format("edit_{0}", patch.PatchID) />
                            </div>
                            <div class="SaveButton">
                                <input type="button" class="button SaveButton hidden" 
                                       value=""
                                       id=@string.Format("save_{0}", patch.PatchID) />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @wong2 - ASP.NET MVC3 Razor View Engine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$('.EditButton')` will match the `div` and `input` with the `.EditButton` classes.  The `input` is giving you the 63, whereas the `div` is giving you the NaN since it doesn't have an `id` attribute.

I would remove the `.EditButton` class from the div (unless you have it for styling) to prevent the click handler from being called twice.

Comment: Great Thanks! It's amazing what simple mistakes you make that are such a challenge to see yourself :)

Answer (score 2):

Several things going on here. First of all, you're applying the `EditButton` class to both the containing div and the input button field. So, both will get a click event handler.

Next, you are only setting the `id` on the button itself.

Next I'm guessing that you are not telling JavaScript that you've processed the event (return `false`, usually), so it's bubbling up through the containment chain. First the button processes the click and then the div container.

Comment: Sorry I'm very new to JS. Could you explain where the return false should go? Should that be in every javascript function?

Comment: Here's an example in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qP58y/4/ 
In essence: return false is to stop the event bubbling up to the parent container. Run the example with it commented out, then with it uncommented to see the difference.

Comment: I understand what the idea is, however when I tried your example it still had two alerts with the return statement commented or not commented. Are these return statements necessary in all javascript functions?

Comment: Did you click Run after making the change? Altering the JavaScript doesn't cause the fiddle to be reloaded. 

Returning false is only necessary in event handlers to ensure that the event doesn't bubble up the chain to its parent. General JavaScript functions don't need you to return false as a matter of course. (For example, the jQuery function returns a jQuery collection.)

Comment: I did not click Run after making the change. Thanks. Now it works. I should have known it wouldn't be reloaded, I just didn't spend the time looking for the answer ;). Thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 1):

your classnames appears twice and are one in the other. I mean you just have to remove class="EditButton" and class="SaveButton" from the div's elements !

Here are more details :

When you click the input button, it'll trigger many click events, one for the element you clicked on, and one for each parent of this element.

Since you affect the event to all element sharing a common classname, using $, and you have two of theses elements one in another, the event will be triggered twice.

You can also add an id to both of your div's then, the second Console.log wil report this value  !

Answer (score 0):

You have the same class name ("EditButton") on both your button and the `div` that contains it. That means the jQuery click handler is being fired twice for a click on the button - once for the button itself, and once for the containing `div`.

To fix this, you can either remove or change the class from the parent `div`, or check the `event.target` in the event handler function, to see if the button was clicked or not.